# Is it a proper way to indicate the number of replies

Tags: support, answers

I asked a question on the Stack Overflow and I got some feedback. The number next to the icon "Recent inbox messages" said to be 4. However when I clicked on it to display the list of messages I saw only one - the last one and it was displayed as a new one (selected with blue colour).

Is it expected behaviour? Or maybe it was introduced very recently? I remember it was not like this in the past and it made me wonder.

Comment: That's nothing new. That list shows one "cell" for each post. You just got 4 comments for one post, I guess your question.

Comment: This still confuses me from time to time, you just learn to get used to it :)

Comment: @Tom, but I should see 4 lines in the list, no? Because the number shows how many new messages I received. Now surprisingly enough, I see 4 replies to this post and lines in the list. I guess one is for the answer and 3 for the comments. Is this how it should look like? I mean all those comments you guys posted are new and so should appear as the new posts in that list..3

Answer (score 3):

Comments on the same post are grouped together; you just got 4 comments on the same post. Just remember to scroll up a bit and you should be fine.